# Using the truth table, determine the validity of following argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Using the truth table, determine the validity of following argument:

```
    If you invest in business, then you get profit.
    You didn't invest in business.
    Therefore, you didn't get profit.
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the formal logic behind "if... then..." statements?

Comment: What did you try? What are your prepositions? Can you translate that sentence into one with the logical operators?

Answer (score 0):

let $ i:$ invest in business and $p:$ get profits

$A\equiv$"If you invest in business, then you get profit"$\equiv i\rightarrow p \equiv \neg i \vee p$

$B\equiv$You didn't invest in business. Therefore, you didn't get profit."$\equiv \neg i \rightarrow \neg p\equiv i \vee \neg p$ 
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
i & p & A & B\\
\hline
T & T & T & T\\
T & F & F & T\\
F & T & T & F\\
F & F & T & T\\
\hline
\end{array}

Because of statement A is True, only lines 1, 3 and 4 are correct.

But that does not mean that B  is True as shown by line 3.

(It is possible not to invest and to get profits, statement A does notcontradict that).

So the argument is false.